# do_shortcode within loop only returns content for first post

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode that is supposed to return the title and content for multiple custom posts on a single page. It correctly displays the title for each post, but when it comes to displaying each post's content, it only displays the content from the first post. What am I doing wrong?

Figuring out how to get the content from within a shortcode has been tricky enough, so if anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it!

My code is:

```
 if($customposts->have_posts() ) : while ($customposts->have_posts() ) : $customposts->the_post();
     $post= get_the_ID();
    $foo = get_the_title();
    $bar=do_shortcode($content);
    echo "<h2>".$foo."</h2><p>".$bar."</p>";    


endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: I'm guessing that $content is set outside the loop, and therefore you always get the same result.

Comment: It is set outside this loop in my shortcode function.

Comment: What is `$content`?

Comment: I don't think it was actually doing anything...I just removed it, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: You're actually not accessing the content anywhere.  See my solution below about `get_the_content()`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need to us `do_shortcode`.  If `title` is working correctly, you should be able to assign `get_the_content()` to your `$bar` variable.

```
$bar = get_the_content();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looping through posts, store the html from each iteration of the loop, and then return all of the html at once (remember, you can't echo or print from a shortcode callback... well, you *shouldn't*, or you'll get some unexpected results):

```
$html = '';
    if($customposts->have_posts() ) : 
        while ($customposts->have_posts() ) : $customposts->the_post();
        $post= get_the_ID();
        $foo = get_the_title();
        $bar = get_the_content();
        $html .= "<h2>$foo</h2><p>$bar</p>";
    endwhile; endif;

return $html;
```

Also, be careful about using `$post` as your own variable, you will undoubtedly come into conflict with other scripts, including core.

Comment: I am using a shortcode..this loop is within my shortcode function. Also using the_content() within a shortcode causes a fatal error.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your intent. I edited my answer.